# HostAuthenticationAttribute not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This error has been driving me insane all day. How do I fix it? I've updated NUGET with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin but still no luck.

```
Error   11  The type or namespace name 'HostAuthenticationAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   12  The type or namespace name 'HostAuthentication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    


// GET api/Account/ExternalLogin
        [OverrideAuthentication]
        **[HostAuthentication**(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the packages had different versions and because I had multiple projects in 1 Solutions it wasn't easy to see. Yes can be mundane but recheck everything thrice please and get a second eye sometimes helps.